# Selenium check for text otherwise prompts the next task

Tags: python, selenium

On python 3.9 and selenium 4.0.0

So I'm currently trying to go to a website and check if there is text there like "Please enter your username" and if that text is not there, it'll open up a different tab and go to a different website.

This is my current code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())  # opens a new chrome window
driver.maximize_window()  # maximizes the window
driver.get('website.com')

if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="outside"]/div[4]/div/p [contains(text(), "Please enter your Username and Password to continue.")]').click() is True:
    loginBox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="username"]') 
    loginBox.send_keys("username") 

    password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type = "password"]')
    password.send_keys("password")
else:
    pass

driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','secondtab');")
driver.switch_to.window("secondtab")
driver.get("secondwebsite.com")
...
```

It currently just opens the website and sits there while not checking for any of the conditions I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.click` returns type is void, so it would not make any sense to have it returned as true.

Also, if you use `find_elements` (**Plural**), you would have a `list`.

Please use the below code :

```
try:
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='outside']/div[4]/div/p [contains(text(), 'Please enter your Username and Password to continue.')]")) > 0:
        print("This means that the above xpath is valid and have a node in HTMLDOM")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='outside']/div[4]/div/p [contains(text(), 'Please enter your Username and Password to continue.')]"))).click()
        loginBox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="username"]')
        loginBox.send_keys("username")

        password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type = "password"]')
        password.send_keys("password")
    else:
        print("Please check this xpath, //*[@id='outside']/div[4]/div/p [contains(text(), 'Please enter your Username and Password to continue.')]")
        pass
except:
    pass

driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','secondtab');")
driver.switch_to.window("secondtab")
driver.get("secondwebsite.com")
```

I have induced `Explicit waits (WebDriverWait)`, Please use below imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//*[@id='outside']/div[4]/div/p [contains(text(), 'Please enter your Username and Password to continue.')]
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for some element containing `Please enter your Username and Password to continue.` text immediately after opening that page with `driver.get('website.com')`.
This may cause that you checking this element content while it is still not fully rendered.
Also,

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="outside"]/div[4]/div/p [contains(text(), "Please enter your Username and Password to continue.")]').click()
```

Doesn't return Boolean, it returns nothing.
So it is never `True`
That's why you immediately passed to the `else` where you doing nothing, just `pass`